# How to stream online radio with Phonegap?

Tags: ios, audio, streaming, cordova, icecast

I have hard time getting an iphone app built on top of phonegap to stream online radio station. It should be possible but doing

```
try {
     var myaudio = new Media('http://domain.com:8000/ices',function(e)  
          {alert(e);},function(e){alert(e);});
                myaudio.play();
        } catch (e) {
                 alert('no audio support!');
     }
```

does not play the stream. No error either. The app just freezes and no error in the Xcode log console.

How should i approach this?

Answer (score 4):

I've done this by using HTML5 ...
Simply create an AUDIO instance and use SRC to call URL STREAM.
Audio player will be visible but you can hide it easily!

Comment: @ Dalibor Vlaho How do you do that?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the Media api in iOS doesn't support streaming.

https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-iphone/issues/55

If you are willing to work with a code that is still in development (not sure I have all the kinks out of it yet) then I have written a plugin using Matt Gallagher's AudioStreamer classes  that so far seems to work great on iOS:

https://github.com/devgeeks/phonegap-plugins/tree/AudioStreamer/iPhone/AudioStream

If you do try it out and find any bugs, make sure to let me know :)

EDIT: This plugin never got truly completed and is probably NOT the best solution. I worry people are still upvoting this, heh. For streaming in PhoneGap and iOS it is probably best to use straight HTML5 audio. It works a treat.

Comment: MPMoviePlayer seems to do the job without a plug-in... is there something i am missing?

Comment: The original questioner asked about PhoneGap. MPMoviePlayer requires native iOS development (Objective-C).

Comment: @Abhishek - Nope. The issue is now here (since they moved to the apache incubator infrastructure): https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-57

Comment: @Abhishek - I even abandoned my plugin and ended up using straight html5/js for my radio streaming app starting with the info here: http://www.joeldare.com/wiki/play_an_mp3_audio_stream_in_phonegap

Comment: @Devgeeks mhmm i think i amma deep dive C and write one for self then :(

Comment: @ Abhishek always welcome to just fork mine and try and fix the remote button stuff. There is an issue open for it on GitHub.

Comment: @Devgeeks forked ^^ now lets go dirty c LOL

Comment: @Devgeeks by the way the <html> / <js> Player thing will it work on lower end iOS ?

Comment: @Abhishek It certainly works on a 3GS, not sure about older versions of iOS.

Comment: HTML5 audio on iOS is limited to simple MP3 and will fail for all other popular formats (i.e. AAC used by iTunes).